# Is there a limit on how long a cfquery with cfqueryparam can get?

Tags: coldfusion

I have some code that does a tight loop to insert thousands+ records and recently when I introduce `<cfqueryparam>`, CF crashes.

Something like...

```
<cfquery>
  <cfloop query="qBars">
    INSERT INTO Foo 
    SET 
      xx = <cfqueryparam value="#qBars.aa#" sqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
      yy = <cfqueryparam value="#qBars.bb#" sqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
  </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

This used to work beautifully without `<cfqueryparam>`.  With cfqueryparam however, I guess it might be problematic when the recordcount of `qBars` is large (10,000+).

Now... What shall I do?  Refactor the whole thing to be handled in DB level?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting your `cfquery` inside your `cfloop` so you run one statement in 000s of queries rather than 000s of statements in one query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be honest, if I was needing to load 10k+ records into the DB, I would not use CFQUERY.  Your DB will almost certainly have the capability to bulk load data, so I recommend investigating that.

I think the maximum number of bind parameters allowed would be a restriction set by the DB engine rather than by CF or the underlying JDBC.  But you don't mention which DB you're using, so it's hard to research an answer for you there.

I did some snooping around and found this table for SQL Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx.  It does not specifically mention how many bind params an inline query can have, but the figure of 2100 they mention for params for a proc or function is the same as the maximum number of parameters I've been able to pass in a list before (like for a WHERE IN clause).  I always thought it was the maximum size for a list, but perhaps it's actually the cut off for how many params in general.  This would be easy for you to test... try your loop with 1005 iterations and see if it works.  Then try it with 1006 iterations, and me might expect it to fail.

That is, of course, if you happen to be on SQL Server...

Also, you say the thing crashes, but you don't say what the error is... it's always helpful to include this sort of information when you're asking this sort of question.

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm using SQL Server, and no, it does not produce any crash / exception info but the server will not respond to anything again anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Antony has a good suggestion... I would check to see what impact this has on your problem. Personally, I'd lean towards refactoring. I've had great success in moving data intensive operations to the database level.

I'm currently responsible for an application that parses and analyzes keywords. The parser was originally written in coldfusion, which worked great. As the volume of entries to process grew (almost exponentially), the process itself became very slow. I rewrote the code in t-SQL (I'm running SS2K8) and the response time increased substantially. imho, refactoring is worth the time, especially on data intensive operations.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the code to

```
<cfloop query="qBars">
    <cfquery>
    INSERT INTO Foo 
    SET 
      xx = <cfqueryparam value="#qBars.aa#" sqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">,
      yy = <cfqueryparam value="#qBars.bb#" sqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

And see what happens. If that works, you can wrap a <cftransaction around the whole thing which will send all the inserts in one transaction rather than thousands.

Comment: good idea, I'll try this.  However, the performance will suffer a lot, no?

Comment: IF it works then the performance is much better vs. having the server stop responding.  If you send them as one transaction then there will be only one COMMIT, and only one re-indexing. So I do not think the performance hit would be bad. I could be wrong, I am no DBA.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
INSERT INTO ''foo'' (''xx'',''yy'') 
VALUES 
    <cfloop query="qBars">
    (<cfqueryparam value="#qBars.aa#" sqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">, <cfqueryparam value="#qBars.bb#" sqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR">)
    <cfif NOT qBars.currentRecordcount eq qBars.recordcount>,</cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

I think this will work. I have not tried it recently, but I am pretty sure I have used it in the past. I modified this example for another SO answer.

Comment: Just a note, I believe that syntax requires ms sql 2008+

Comment: is this syntax better in any other way, other then cleaner?

Comment: @JasonDean: But this will not allow more than 1000 values to insert.